# What is the best android sdk version to use

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android. I installed android version 22.3 and tried to add Google Play services , that need to update it to 23.0 . But it did not allow to complete.
So I installed ADT bundle with SDK rev 23.0.2 now it take long time to load , and some emulators are not loading , they encounter a problem while loading. Also it take 20 min or so to load. I am using eclipse. 
1.Is that a problem of sdk rev-23.0.2 ?
2.What is the best version of SDK to use?

Comment: Newest one is the best

Comment: Thanks,It take long time to load , and since I have no hardwre device I use emulator . Can you please tell me ,are there any tips to increase performance. And also some AVD are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, try to download from sdk Manager the GingerBread and KitKat APIs
And try this emulator : [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) a lot of people used to have troubles running the standard emulator but when switching to GenyMotion life became easier

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to get free version . Is that enough to develop location aware apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works well, But I can't run apps using google play services.

Comment: install google play services from SDK manager

Comment: You mean in Eclipse IDE SDK manager? I did that but how to create a genimotion VD with Google Play service

Comment: I have installed SDK platform Android4.4W andAndroid 4.4.2API19 both is their any impact in loading AVD . Mine is very very slow. But now I use Genymotion but it not allow to drag n drop Gapp there comes "Flash error"